# How can pass my row values from datagridView to another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, buttonclick

I have two forms-Main and AddToCurrentInventory.In the Main form I have a datagridview and a button 'Add to Current Inventory'.I want to select a row(by single click) from the datagridview and pass the values of few columns to controls of AddtoCurrentInventory form which is opened when I click on 'Add To current Inventory' button.Hence,I have to trigger two events at the same time.I tried to do so but they are not getting triggered.When I click the button ,it opens up another form but the values are not passes from the selected row.Where am I going wrong?

Here is the code for the two methods I defined-

```
private void dataGridInventoryItems_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridViewInventoryItems.Rows[rowIndex];
        AddToCurrentInventory form=new AddToCurrentInventory();
        form.labelItemno.Text=row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        //label on the form AddtocurrentInventory
        form.textBox_itemname.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
       //textbox on the form AddToCurrentInventory
        form.cmbUnit.Text= row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
       //ComboBox on the form AddToCurrentInventory

    }

    private void button_addtocurrent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddToCurrentInventory formAddToCurrentInventory = new AddToCurrentInventory();

        formAddToCurrentInventory.Show();
    }
```

These methoda are made in the Main form.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work because within Cell click you are creating an instance of `AddToCurrentInventory` and setting the field values but within button click you are creating another instance of AddToCurrentInventory to display the form. Use the same instance where you set the value to show the form as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some variables to store all the values extracted in the `CellClick`, then use these variables to pass info to your **new** form. However you should declare a variable holding your new form. Your form should also be created just once. Here is how it should be done:

```
//You just need handle the button Click event    
private void button_addtocurrent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                  
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridViewInventoryItems.CurrentRow;   
    if(!row.IsNewRow) {
      AddToCurrentInventory form=new AddToCurrentInventory();        
      form.labelItemno.Text=row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
      //label on the form AddtocurrentInventory
      form.textBox_itemname.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
      //textbox on the form AddToCurrentInventory
      form.cmbUnit.Text= row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
      form.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare one global variable for storing current index of the row. say

```
Public int row =0;


 private void button_addtocurrent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                  
 row = new_tab_Object.CurrentCell.RowIndex; 

  if (row != -1)
    {
  AddToCurrentInventory form=new AddToCurrentInventory();

  form.labelItemno.Text=row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

  //label on the form AddtocurrentInventory

  form.textBox_itemname.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
  //textbox on the form AddToCurrentInventory
  form.cmbUnit.Text= row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
  form.Show();
}
```

}